# How would I know if the counter increments are at the correct place to keep track the # of comparisons ~ C++?

Tags: c++, function, sorting, vector, insertion

// Question solved. I am confused on where to add the counters at to report the number of
comparisons. It always stay at a fixed number and never changes. Assume the vector contain two-digit random numbers every time the program runs. //

**Edit: New question. I'm not sure if the counter increments are at the correct place or not for insertion sort and selection sort. 
Code pasted at a safe link:** http://ideone.com/Bk90du

```
int insertionSort(vector<int> &v)
{
// Variables
int temp, i, j, counter;
counter = 0;

for (i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
{
        temp = v[i];

        j = i-1;
        while(temp < v[j] && j >= 0)
        {
            v[j+1]=v[j];
            j--;
            counter++; // tracking # of comparisons. 

        }
        v[j+1]=temp;
}
return counter; // return counter 
}
```

Comment: I think the error is somewhere else, this should work.

Comment: what kind of error? @alain

Comment: How do you fill the input vector with values? Do you seed the random number generator properly?

Comment: Made some changes to my question, would appreciate your input and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

According to the (now deleted) comment, this is `main()`:

```
int main() {
    int numCount;
    vector<int> myVector2(myVector);
    insertionSort(myVector2);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Vector after Insertion Sort: ";
    printVector(myVector2);
    cout << endl << endl;
    numCount = insertionSort(myVector2);
    cout << "Number of comparisons: " << numCount;
```

You sort the same vector two times, and print the comparision count of the second sort run. When the vector is already sorted, the number of comparisons is equal to the number of elements in the vector, because no work has to be done.

To get the true number of comparisons, change your `main()` to:

```
int main() {
    int numCount;
    vector<int> myVector2(myVector);
    numCount = insertionSort(myVector2);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Vector after Insertion Sort: ";
    printVector(myVector2);
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Number of comparisons: " << numCount;
```

Comment: I have a question, for the comparisons for the reverse vectors. They rarely change at all, if they do change, it is only a minor difference. Is that suppose to happen? But, for the original vectors of myVector and myVector2, I got them to both work thanks with your comment :)

Comment: The reverse vector is also sorted, but reversed, so yes, I would say it's normal that the number of comparisons is the same most of the time. The (small) differences occur probably when there are duplicate elements.

Comment: I'm not sure if the counter increments are at the correct place or not.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your test cases are, it's not possible to comment on number of comparisons they perform.   If all cases have similar attributes, it is quite possible the code is behaving as it should.

**EDIT:**   the following added in response to claim by OP in comments that the test cases are vectors with 100 randomly generated two-digit elements.

If, as you have said in comments, your test cases involve vectors with 100 random two-digit values, then the value of `counter` will depend on how "unsorted" the elements are (with the minimum value possible related to the number of elements).   Assuming all of your test cases are the same size, then the only way the value of `counter` will be the same is if the vectors are sorted similarly BEFORE calling your function.   For example, if all your vectors are pre-sorted in ascending order and the same size, every test case will give the exact same return value.   Similarly, if all your vectors are pre-sorted in descending order and the same size, every test case will give the exact same return value (albeit different from the value returned if they are initially in ascending order).

For that reason, I do not believe your comment that the test cases are random.   They are probably presorted (or maybe partially sorted) in some way.   For example, you might be calling your function twice for each test case, and only printing out the value of `count` after the second call ..... when  the vector is (if your code behaves as it should) already pre-sorted.

**End Edit**

That said, the variable `counter` in your code is accumulating the number of times the body of the `while` loop is executed.  That has nothing to do with number of comparisons being performed, as there is no comparison performed in the body of that loop.    It is related to the number of insertions, not the number of comparisons.

If, by "comparison", you want mean evaluating the expression `temp < v[j]` (as distinct from other expressions, like `i < v.size()` or `j >= 0`, which could also be called comparisons in your code) then you might consider doing something like

```
while (++counter && temp < v[j] && j >= 0)
```

and removing incrementing of `counter` from the loop body.

Since `counter` is initialised to zero, this will count the number of times `temp < v[j]` is evaluated (`++counter` will always produce a non-zero result).   Note that, since `temp < v[j]` can be false, it will not count the number of times `j >= 0` is computed.

Comment: The test cases are: a vector has 100 random two-digit numbers, the insertion sort function will sort the numbers into ascending order. The counter increments in the function, so it can return the number of comparisons it makes.

Comment: Yeah, okay.   I've edited my answer in response to your claim here.   Somehow, I doubt your test cases are actually random.   But the explanation is too long to give in a comment.